# Clean up of old dev models in OLAP folder of SSAS server

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have several SSAS servers that I maintain. When a user creates a tabular database in Visual Studio, SSDT creates a development copy of their database with this naming convention: ModelName_UserID_GUID. Many users have left the group, but these dev copies are still in the \OLAP folder. Is there an official way to clean these out, or can I just delete the folders on the server? I don't have storage issues at the moment, but I don't like crud lurking in my servers.

Answer (score 0):

@Mrizza,
Easy way would be to login to the analysis service instance and right click on the unwanted cubes and delete them.
It should also clean up the backend spaces :)

Comment: These databases he is talking about are likely detached. So they won’t be visible when connected to the server. They are “workspace” databases which get detached when the developer closes Visual Studio.

Comment: @GregGalloway you are correct. Some of these workspace databases were never deployed, so there never was a production database, and the workspace database was detached when they closed Visual Studio. Nandan any ideas?